# What is the value for the cgroup's limit_in_bytes if the memory is not restricted/unlimited?

Tags: memory, docker, cgroups

Printing the value of an unlimited docker container I get the value 9223372036854771712 which is 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFF000 (this is the same value of the XUbuntu Host machine). I couldn't find a reference that this is the Docker or Linux default value indicating an unlimited memory resource.

Where does this value come from?
Is it different between Container Virtualizations or Linux Distributions/Bitnesses?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The value comes from the cgroup setup in the memory management layer; by default, it’s [set to `PAGE_COUNTER_MAX`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/memcontrol.c#n3127), which is [`LONG_MAX / PAGE_SIZE`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/page_counter.h) on 64-bit platforms, and [multiplied by `PAGE_SIZE` again when read](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/memcontrol.c#n2729).

This confirms [ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu)’s [explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420911/86440): the value is the maximum 64-bit signed integer, rounded to the nearest page (by dropping the last bits).

Answer (score 11):

That's the highest positive signed 64-bit integer (2<sup>63</sup>-1), rounded down to multiples of 4096 (2<sup>12</sup>), the most common page size on x86 systems. It would seem difficult to get anything higher while avoiding possible confusion between signed and unsigned, so it seems at least a reasonable approximation for infinity.

That said, I don't know for sure, this is just a guess.